# Laravel env vars in bootstrap/app.php?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I put this in `bootstrap/app.php`

```
dump(env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'));
```

and it's coming back `null` even though this environment variable is set in my `.env` file.

I suspect that file hasn't loaded by the time `bootstrap/app.php` runs.

What file *does* run after the env files are loaded? Is there another startup file where I can put this sort of thing?

Comment: did you try after clear your config cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)**
You can use `env()` only in config files `config/*.php` but there are some trick. Add this code at the beginning of `bootstrap/app.php`:

```
try
{
    (new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__.'/../'))->load();
}
catch (Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $ignored) { }
```

[Look here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19986).

**2)** You can do it in `AppServiceProvider` file.

Comment: He has seen the link that you are referring. He had commented 9 hours ago before you post your answer.

Comment: Indeed, I saw that thread. Loading the Dotenv file early seems like a hack -- it's just going to do it again later.

Comment: @mpen you are right but I don't think that you will find good decision for your task if you uses `env()` in other place except `config/*.php`.

Comment: How does putting it under `config/*.php` help me though? This isn't a new config var I'm trying to set, I need to execute some code. So sure, I can create a new `config/stripe.php` but then what? How do I run my code after *that* is loaded?

Comment: @mpen What about call `dump(env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'));` in `AppServiceProvider` or this is not suit for you?

Comment: @mpen I have updated answer (put this answer as second variant).